# Data Type Double seemingly overflowing when it shouldn't in a custom class

Tags: class, excel, integer-overflow, vba

I get a weird [error](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa264525(v=vs.60).aspx) (overflow, error '6') with the following highlight:

[image: Overflow]

The value in arg3 has been modified after fetching because this is taken from a production dataset, but the 3 first digits has been preserved in the probably-farfetched case of this error being intrinsic to the datatype.

I assigned the original value to a `Double` var in a test sub and there were no issues, which I can only interpret as this not being a problem with `Double` in itself. Is the object overflowing, somehow, and if so, why?

This error does not arise when `arg3 = 0`, and subsequently, objects are created as expected in these cases.

Comment: How is `pTelephone` declared and why are you using a numeric type rather than string? You presumably won't be doing calculations with it.

Comment: `Private pTelephone As Double`. I don't have to use numeric, but I opted to because I am putting the values into a worksheet again and wanted to avoid casting back and forth. It wouldn't take long to try with string instead, so I'll do that.

Comment: Using string, there are no more overflow errors. Workaround successful!

Comment: I don't know if you are doing it on purpose, but you are passing argArray(15) to CreateParticipant twice :)
Off-topic, I know, but thought you should know.

Comment: Not on purpose, no. That shouldn't (and doesn't, to the extent that I have seen) raise any errors since they are the same datatypes,  but it sure would create some very interesting data. Thanks for the heads up :)